# unexpected print output in python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm doing a python 3 tutorial and i'm trying to figure out where in my output  these parentheses are coming from.

```
students = int (input())
total = dict()
for i in range(0,students):
  tokens = input().split()
  name = tokens[0]
  total[name] = float(tokens[1]) + float(tokens[2]) + float(tokens[3])

student = input(())
print ("{0:.2f}".format(total[student] / 3))
```

Expected Output

```
56.00
```

My Output

```
()56.00
```

Answer (score 2):

replace this:

```
student = input(())
```

with:

```
student = input()
```

This is what happening :

```
 >>> student = input(())
()
```

Answer (score 0):

In `student = input(())` you are passing an empty tuple as the prompt argument to the `input` function. Normally, you pass `input` a prompt *string*, however `input` (and `raw_input` in Python 2) will happily accept any object for the prompt and convert it to a string, just like `print` does. If no prompt is supplied then no prompt gets printed. (I *suspect* that `input` simply passes the prompt to `print`).

So your unexpected `()` is simply that empty tuple, converted to a string.